# Remmina connection via gateway not working from one machine when in certain network

Tags: network-manager, remote-desktop, remmina

I am facing a weird issue. My company has a remote desktop server, which can be accessed via a gateway. Remmina is configured and workes well with that connection when I'm at work with my laptop.

However, when I am at home and connected to the internet via my home network (Fritzbox router, NAT), that same machine cannot reach the remote desktop server. Remmina tries connecting, and after a few seconds simply aborts with the unhelpful message "Connection to RDP server 1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx failed." (The message shows a real IP, it is another one than the gateway's IP, so I assume some forwarding fails.).

The same failure happens when using a WIFI network at work, e.g. eduroam.

Now to the really weird part: Another (privat) computer at home, likewise running Ubuntu 18.04, has no problem whatsoever connecting to that same remote desktop server. It was configured the same way as the work laptop, and everything workes like a charm.

So, to summarize:

- Work laptop, within work network → works
- Home laptop, within home network → works
- Work laptop, within eduroam wireless network → does NOT work
- Work laptop, within home wired network → does NOT work
- Work laptop, within home wireless network → does NOT work

Apparently, the issue is not with the home router configuration for this machine, there are no restrictions or differences set up at all (compared to the other machine that *does* work). I would assume it's some obscure network setting set up somewhere within the OS of the work computer (repeatedly upgraded from former Ubuntu versions). But I have no idea as to where to look, and couldn't find relevant logs so far.

By now I also know that a number of other colleagues – not all of them using Ubuntu as their Linux distro – encounter the same issue when trying to work from a network other than the wired work network. The error looks the same for them. However, usually, they get shown another related IP address each for the failed forwarding.

Would anybody possibly have any pointers for us? :)

Comment: I'd start by comparing the network-interface settings between your home and work laptops, check for static DNS-settings, maybe some static routing...

Comment: I did compare the network-interface settings between both my machines, and didn't see any real differences, let alone relevant-looking ones. There are no static DNS settings or routings set up, as far as I can tell. Also, as stated in the edited question, I'm not the only one of my colleagues affected by this.